# Android. Изменение view выбора даты

Tags: android, view, datepicker, calendar

Здравствуйте.
В приложении необходимо выбрать дату. Используется стандартный DatePickerDialog.
При отображении выбора даты, календарь выглядит в Европейском стиле (Воскресенье - первый день недели). Как изменить выбор даты так, чтобы первым днем недели был понедельник?

[image: Стандартное отображение]

---

И сразу второй вопрос касательно этой view.
Как заменить обозначения дней недели
с [П, В, С, Ч, П, С, В]
на [Пн, Вт, Ср, Чт, Пт, Сб, Вс]
[image: Эти обозначения интересуют]

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27?sort=created , может тут найдете что-то по душе.

Comment: Что-то с локалью не то. Попробуйте установить Locale ru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

это можно сделать, к примеру, в методах onCreate()/onCreateView() ваших активити/фрагмента

```
date = (DatePicker) value.findViewById(R.id.date);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
    date.getCalendarView().setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
}
```

либо строчкой ниже можно привязаться к локали:

```
date.getCalendarView().setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.getInstance().getFirstDayOfWeek());
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423516/5887158